# Vector Grid Layer on QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

In QGIS, I'm trying to create a vector grid layer with cells 150m x 150m, yet it only seems to be possible in degrees.

Is there a setting I need to change, or is there an equivalence I can use to convert degrees to meters?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set your **Project** CRS to something using meters, like UTM or State plane. Then you can use `Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid ...` to create a grid in the same projection.

You should set the `X` parameter to something useful, e.g. 150 for a 150m-grid.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a layer which you want to create the grid layer from? If so make a buffer around them. Use the extend of the bufferlayer to make the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Oh and if not, then try this.

1. Create a polygon layer that covers the area you want to create a grid within.
2. Then use from Processing Toolbox: Create graticule --> Set your Grid extend by your polygon layer.
3. Define the horisontal and vertical spacing and run it.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS 3.10:

```
Processing Toolbox | Vector Creation | Create Grid
```

In this tool, you can draw the extent on the canvas, select from canvas or manually input the bounding coordinates. Also, you can select the vertical as well as horizontal spacing in the respective unit.